# Subordinate clauses headed by "With"

Tags: sentence, subordinate-clauses, ielts

There are some subordinate clauses headed by *with*. For example:

> A company can adopt a standardized approach or an internal models
> approach, **with the former generally leading to much higher capital
> charges and the latter requiring regulatory approval**.

> the number of graduations by international students rose significantly in the 5-year period, **with all universities seeing an increase**, with the exception of Alberta.

Here are my questions:

1. What is the role of *with* in such clauses?
2. Do these clauses indicate a result/consequence? For example, *the number of graduations by international students rose significantly in the 5-year period, <s>with all universities seeing an increase</s> as a result of increases seen by all universities, with the exception of Alberta.*

**EDIT**: To make my question more clear, I modified the post. The original post was: There are some subordinate clauses headed by *with*. What is the role of *with* in the sentences below? And as stated by [1](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/avoid-beginning-a-sentence-with-with/), is such a structure doomed to be weak and it has to be avoided?

Comment: So *with* is now a four-letter word? Oy. Doomed? It's just one person's opinion.

Comment: And here I thought it was a mere preposition, with no significant consequences.

Comment: Why avoid it if everyone can understand the meaning?

Comment: The word "with" at the beginning of the bold text could be just dropped in all three examples.

Comment: Modern grammar classifies "with" as a preposition, so the _with_ expressions are PPs with "with" as **head"**. Functionally, the PPs are probably best analysed as supplementary adjuncts.

Answer (score 2):

One reason to avoid such a *with* phrase is that it is, itself, used to avoid absolute constructions, by authors who either deem their audience unworthy, or who fail to think of them at all. And so it is sometimes felt to be a less literate substitute.

Note: *with* phrases can be used to great effect, but the ones in your examples could be replaced with normal absolute constructions.